# How to clear Go env in Makefile?

Tags: go, makefile

I have a host that is set up to download `go` dependencies from a private corporate `gitlab` repo. I have a couple of dependent services on `github` in a **private** repository. When I try to run `go mod tidy` I get an error

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I already changed a git config so git commands run well:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

My assumption is that the problem is `go envs`. I added the following to the `Makefile`:

```makefile
NEW_GOPRIVATE=github.com/user-name

.PHONY: envs
envs:
    GOPRIVATE=$(NEW_GOPRIVATE) go env

.PHONY: deps
deps:
    GOPRIVATE=$(NEW_GOPRIVATE) go mod tidy
```

When I run `make envs` I see that some values are still filled and I need to empty them.

```
GOINSECURE="gitlab.work.corp.com"
GONOPROXY="github.com/user-name"
GONOSUMDB="github.com/user-name"
```

When I compare to values on computer where it works I see that these values are empty. How can I "clear" values in Makefile?

Comment: It should work to just add `GOINSECURE=` (that is set them to empty).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help:

Comment: EMPTY_VAR=
...
GOINSECURE=$(EMPTY_VAR) go env

Comment: I don't know why you added the `EMPTY_VAR=` indirection here, and it's kind of wrong because `$(EMPTY_VAR)` refers to the **make** variable `EMPTY_VAR` not the **shell** variable `EMPTY_VAR`, but since it's highly unlikely there is a `make` variable named `EMPTY_VAR` set, it's all the same thing.  Of course, you have to reset every variable that you don't want to have a value, to empty.  You can't just set `GOINSECURE` and have the others set to empty as well.  You'll need to elaborate on what you mean by "it doesn't help".  Edit your question with the change, and results.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to say that `GOINSECURE= go env` also doesn't help - `$ GOINSECURE= go env GOINSECURE` returns `gitlab.work.corp.com`

Comment: Well, something is clearly overriding the value from the caller's environment.  I don't know enough about how `go` works; maybe it's loading this value from somewhere else.